# static export in next js doesn't load when i reload the page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am using  next js frame work and i want use static export but there is problem here.

for example i have URL www.sitename.com/about

when i go there for the first time it works but when i reload the page i get 404 page.

i use route like this if helps :

```
<Link href="/about">
    <a className='nav-link' >
        <span className='ml-2'>about</span>
    </a>
</Link>
```

if you can help i really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried www.sitename.com/about.html?

Answer (score 1):

I will explain by using my code example:

My `package.json` contains this script: `"build": "next build && next export"`.

When I run: `npm run build` NextJS creates the folder `out`, for example:
[image]

I created `next.config.js` and added the next code, [from here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap#adding-a-trailing-slash):

```
module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true,
  }
```

and re-run: `npm run build`

Now, folder `out` contains sub-folder for each page(route) and `index.html` file inside created folders.

[image]

I am hosting on AWS S3 bucket, the next screenshot from there:

[image]

As you can see, I uploaded all sub-folders from `out` folder except `404`.
I renamed `index.html` from `404` to `404.html` and uploaded it.

Now it works.

Downside - It's not convenient to upload many folders in S3 bucket.